# .empty() to clear tbody element when table dynamically created

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jspdf

I am creating a drop-down list to help people choose media and ink for their printers and then generate a table to view the results. I have reached the point where the table is generated and can be downloaded as a PDF using jspdf, but the problem comes when you select a different printer. I cannot seem to figure out a way to clear the tbody elements first then populate the tbody with the medias and inks.

I have done some research and found that using .empty() works to clear out tbody or divs that have code inside. I cannot figure out a way for the .empty to happen first and then the .each populate the table.

When the drop down is changed and a printer is selected the table populates perfectly. You can then use the download button to get the pdf of the table information. The problem is when you select a second printer the table just populates the list on top of the previous one. The .empty() isn't working first or at all.

```js
function captioncode() {
  var e = document.getElementById("printers");
  var resulting = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  document.getElementById("printertype").innerHTML = resulting + " Supply List";
};

var printersByBrand = {
  HP: ["Select", "HP DesignJet T120", "HP DesignJet T520", "HP DesignJet T730", "HP DesignJet T830 24-Inch", "HP DesignJet T830 36-Inch", "HP DesignJet T930", "HP DesignJet T1530", "HP DesignJet T1600", "HP DesignJet T1700", "HP DesignJet T2530", "HP DesignJet T2600", "HP DesignJet T3500", "HP DesignJet T7200", "HP DesignJet Z6 24-Inch", "HP DesignJet Z6 44-Inch", "HP DesignJet Z9+ 24-Inch", "HP DesignJet Z9+ 44-Inch", "HP DesignJet Z6610 60-Inch", "HP DesignJet Z6810 42-Inch", "HP DesignJet Z6810 60-Inch"],
  Canon: ["Select", "iPF500", "iPF600", "iPF610", "iPF700", "iPF710", "iPF810", "iPF815", "iPF820", "iPF825", "iPFPro-1000", "iPFPro-2000", "iPFPro-4000", "iPFPro-4000s", "iPFPro-6000s", "iPF5000", "iPF5100", "iPF6000", "iPF6100", "iPF6200", "iPF6300", "iPF6300s", "iPF6350", "iPF6400", "iPF6400s", "iPF6450", "iPF8000", "iPF8000s", "iPF8100", "iPF8300", "iPF8300s", "iPF8400", "iPF8400s", "iPF9000", "iPF9000s", "iPF9100", "iPF9400", "iPF9400s", "iPFW8200", "iPFW8400"],
  Mutoh: ["Select", "Mutoh ValueJet 426UF Printer", "Mutoh ValueJet 626UF Printer", "Mutoh ValueJet 628 Printer", "Mutoh ValueJet 1324X Printer with Take-Up Real", "Mutoh ValueJet 1624X Printer with Take-Up Real", "Mutoh ValueJet 1638X Printer with Take-Up Real", "Mutoh ValueJet 2638X Printer", "Mutoh ValueJet 1627MH Hybrid Printer", "Mutoh ValueJet 1638UH Hybrid Printer"]
}

function changecat(value) {
  if (value.length == 0) document.getElementById("printers").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
  else {
    var catOptions = "";
    for (printersId in printersByBrand[value]) {
      catOptions += "<option" + " id='" + printersByBrand[value][printersId] + "'>" + printersByBrand[value][printersId] + "</option>";
    }
    document.getElementById("printers").innerHTML = catOptions;
  }
};

function generate() {
  var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
  var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById("testtest"));
  var header = function(data) {
    doc.setFontSize(18);
    doc.setTextColor(40);
    doc.setFontStyle('normal');
    doc.addImage(logoImg, 'JPEG', data.settings.margin.left, 0, 300, 70);

    var e = document.getElementById("printers");
    var result = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value + " Printer Supplies";
    //doc.addImage(headerImgData, 'JPEG', data.settings.margin.left, 20, 50, 50);
    doc.text(result, data.settings.margin.left, 100);
  };

  var options = {
    beforePageContent: header,
    margin: {
      top: 120
    },
  };

  doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, options);
  var e = document.getElementById("printers");
  var resulting = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  var docusave = resulting + " Printer Supply List"
  doc.save(docusave);
};

var t120Printer = [
  ["HP 711 38-ml Black DesignJet Ink Cartridge", "CZ129A", "$35.98"],
  ["HP 711 29-ml Cyan DesignJet Ink Cartridge", "CZ130A", "$29.92"],
  ["HP 711 29-ml Magenta DesignJet Ink Cartridge", "CZ131A", "$29.92"],
  ["HP 711 29-ml Yellow DesignJet Ink Cartridge", "CZ132A", "$29.92"],
  ["HP 711 80-ml Black DesignJet Ink Cartridge", "CZ133A", "$58.33"],
  ["HP 711 DesignJet Printhead Replacement Kit", "C1Q10A", "$220.24"],
  ["20lb Bond Paper 24 x 150 (2 inch Core)", "B20IJ24X150", "$9.60"],
  ["20lb White Paper 24 x 150 (2 inch Core)", "20BIJ24150", "$9.10"],
  ["24lb Premium Coated Bond Paper 24 x 150 (2 inch Core)", "24IJC24150", "$19.20"],
  ["24lb Premium Coated Bond Paper 24 x 300 (2 inch Core)", "24IJC24300", "$34.47"],
  ["36lb Coated Color Bond Paper 24 x 100 (2 inch Core)", "36IJC24100", "$23.40"],
  ["46lb Premium Coated Color Bond Paper 24 x 100 (2 inch Core)", "46IJC24100", "$33.46"],
  ["Adhesive Matte Polypropylene 24 x 100 (2 inch core)", "QM-WRPPAD-24", "$60.48"]
]
var t520Printer = [
  ["36lb Coated Color Bond Paper 24 x 100 (2 inch Core)", "36IJC24100", "$23.40"],
  ["46lb Premium Coated Color Bond Paper 24 x 100 (2 inch Core)", "46IJC24100", "$33.46"],
  ["Adhesive Matte Polypropylene 24 x 100 (2 inch core)", "QM-WRPPAD-24", "$60.48"]
]

var html = ""

$("#printers").change(function() {
  var e = document.getElementById("printers");
  var resulting = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  if (resulting == "HP DesignJet T120") {
    $('#testtest tbody').empty();

    $.each(t120Printer, function(rowNum, row) {
      console.log(rowNum, row);
      html += "<tr><td>" + row[0] + "<td>" + row[1] + "<td>" + row[2] + "</tr>"
    })

    $((html)).appendTo("#div");
  } else if (resulting == "HP DesignJet T520") {
    $('#testtest tbody').empty();

    $.each(t520Printer, function(rowNum, row) {
      console.log(rowNum, row);
      html += "<tr><td>" + row[0] + "<td>" + row[1] + "<td>" + row[2] + "</tr>"
    })

    $((html)).appendTo("#div");
  } else {
    $((html)).appendTo("#div");
  }
});
```

```css
.PrinterSupplies th,
td,
tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.PrinterSupplies th {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

tbody:last-child::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 25px;
}

.InkSup tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgba(138, 189, 60, 0.15);
}

.MediaSup tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: rgba(66, 51, 82, 0.15)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0096/5813/8703/t/9/assets/jspdf-autotable@2.3.2.js?13018"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0096/5813/8703/files/logo-image-txt.js?13845" type="text/javascript"></script>

<p>Once you have selected something you will need to reload</p><br /><br />

<select name="brand" id="brand" onchange="changecat(this.value);">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
  <option value="HP">HP</option>
  <option value="Canon">Canon</option>
  <option value="Mutoh">Mutoh</option>
</select>
<select name="printers" id="printers" onChange="captioncode()">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
</select>
<br /><br /><br /><br />

<br/><br />
<h1>Test Dynamic Table</h1>
<br /><br />
<div id="pdfsaver">
  <table class="PrinterSupplies" id="testtest">
    <caption id="printertype"></caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="tablehead">Product Name</th>
        <th class="tablehead">Product Sku</th>
        <th class="tablehead">Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="div" class="InkSup"></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<br /><br />
<button onclick="generate();">Download PDF</button>
```

Here is a fiddle to help showcase the problems I am having: https://jsfiddle.net/gza92s5j/

Comment: try empty().append("")

Comment: Note that Java and Javascript are two very different things. I've re-tagged this for you

Comment: I am trying the empty().append('') now and thanks for changing this for me!

Comment: I tried changing my code to this $((html)).empty().appendTo("#div"); but that didn't work. I tried emptying the code first when the dropdown changes like $("#printers").change(function () {
  
  $("#div").empty(); This also doesn't work? @jidexl21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [.remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)

```
$('#testtest tbody tr').remove();
```

Changes wrt to your existing code :

```
$('#testtest tbody tr').remove();
    var html = "";
    $.each(t520Printer, function(rowNum, row){
        //console.log(rowNum, row);
        html += "<tr><td>" + row[0] + "<td>" + row[1] + "<td>" + row[2] + "</tr>"
    })

    $((html)).appendTo("#testtest tbody");
```

I have updated your code with this and it works.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0096/5813/8703/t/9/assets/jspdf-autotable@2.3.2.js?13018"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0096/5813/8703/files/logo-image-txt.js?13845" type="text/javascript"></script>

<p>Once you have selected something you will need to reload</p>
<br /><br />

<select name="brand" id="brand" onchange="changecat(this.value);">
 <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
 <option value="HP">HP</option>
 <option value="Canon">Canon</option>
 <option value="Mutoh">Mutoh</option> 
</select>
<select name="printers" id="printers" onChange="captioncode()">
 <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
 
</select>
<br /><br /><br /><br />

<style>
 .PrinterSupplies th,td,tr{
  border:1px solid black;
 }
 .PrinterSupplies th{
  font-size:25px;
  font-weight: 600;
 }
 tbody:last-child::before{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  height:25px;
 }
 
 .InkSup tr:nth-child(even){
  background-color:rgba(138,189,60,0.15);
 }
 
 .MediaSup tr:nth-child(odd){
  background-color: rgba(66,51,82,0.15)
 }
</style>



<br/><br />
<h1>Test Dynamic Table</h1>
<br /><br />
<div id="pdfsaver">
<table class="PrinterSupplies" id="testtest">
 <caption id="printertype"></caption>
 <thead>
  <tr><th class="tablehead">Product Name</th>
   <th class="tablehead">Product Sku</th>
   <th class="tablehead">Price</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody id="div" class="InkSup">
  
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<br /><br />
<button onclick="generate();">Download PDF</button>

<script>
 
 
 function captioncode() {
  var e = document.getElementById("printers");
  var resulting = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  document.getElementById("printertype").innerHTML = resulting + " Supply List";
 };
 
</script>

<script>
 
var printersByBrand = {
    HP: ["Select", "HP DesignJet T120", "HP DesignJet T520", "HP DesignJet T730", "HP DesignJet T830 24-Inch", "HP DesignJet T830 36-Inch", "HP DesignJet T930", "HP DesignJet T1530", "HP DesignJet T1600", "HP DesignJet T1700", "HP DesignJet T2530", "HP DesignJet T2600", "HP DesignJet T3500", "HP DesignJet T7200", "HP DesignJet Z6 24-Inch", "HP DesignJet Z6 44-Inch", "HP DesignJet Z9+ 24-Inch", "HP DesignJet Z9+ 44-Inch", "HP DesignJet Z6610 60-Inch", "HP DesignJet Z6810 42-Inch", "HP DesignJet Z6810 60-Inch"],
 
    Canon: ["Select", "iPF500", "iPF600", "iPF610", "iPF700", "iPF710", "iPF810", "iPF815", "iPF820", "iPF825", "iPFPro-1000", "iPFPro-2000", "iPFPro-4000", "iPFPro-4000s", "iPFPro-6000s", "iPF5000", "iPF5100", "iPF6000", "iPF6100", "iPF6200", "iPF6300", "iPF6300s", "iPF6350", "iPF6400", "iPF6400s", "iPF6450", "iPF8000", "iPF8000s", "iPF8100", "iPF8300", "iPF8300s", "iPF8400", "iPF8400s", "iPF9000", "iPF9000s", "iPF9100", "iPF9400", "iPF9400s", "iPFW8200", "iPFW8400"],
 
    Mutoh: ["Select", "Mutoh ValueJet 426UF Printer", "Mutoh ValueJet 626UF Printer", "Mutoh ValueJet 628 Printer", "Mutoh ValueJet 1324X Printer with Take-Up Real", "Mutoh ValueJet 1624X Printer with Take-Up Real", "Mutoh ValueJet 1638X Printer with Take-Up Real", "Mutoh ValueJet 2638X Printer", "Mutoh ValueJet 1627MH Hybrid Printer", "Mutoh ValueJet 1638UH Hybrid Printer"]
}

    function changecat(value) {
        if (value.length == 0) document.getElementById("printers").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
        else {
            var catOptions = "";
            for (printersId in printersByBrand[value]) {
                catOptions += "<option" + " id='" + printersByBrand[value][printersId] + "'>" + printersByBrand[value][printersId] + "</option>";
            }
            document.getElementById("printers").innerHTML = catOptions;
        }
    };

 
</script>

<script>
function generate() {

  var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');

  var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById("testtest"));
  
  

  var header = function(data) {
   
    doc.setFontSize(18);
    doc.setTextColor(40);
    doc.setFontStyle('normal');
   
 doc.addImage(logoImg, 'JPEG', data.settings.margin.left, 0, 300, 70);  
   
   var e = document.getElementById("printers");
   var result = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value + " Printer Supplies";
   
    //doc.addImage(headerImgData, 'JPEG', data.settings.margin.left, 20, 50, 50);
  
 
    doc.text(result, data.settings.margin.left, 100);
  };
 
  var options = {
    beforePageContent: header,
    margin: {
      top: 120
    },
    
  };
  
  
 
  doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, options);
  var e = document.getElementById("printers");
  var resulting = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  var docusave = resulting + " Printer Supply List"
  doc.save(docusave);
};
 

</script>



<br /><br />


<script>
  var t120Printer = [
  ["HP 711 38-ml Black DesignJet Ink Cartridge", "CZ129A", "$35.98"],
  ["HP 711 29-ml Cyan DesignJet Ink Cartridge", "CZ130A", "$29.92"],
  ["HP 711 29-ml Magenta DesignJet Ink Cartridge", "CZ131A", "$29.92"],
  ["HP 711 29-ml Yellow DesignJet Ink Cartridge", "CZ132A", "$29.92"],
  ["HP 711 80-ml Black DesignJet Ink Cartridge", "CZ133A", "$58.33"],
  ["HP 711 DesignJet Printhead Replacement Kit", "C1Q10A", "$220.24"],
  ["20lb Bond Paper 24 x 150 (2 inch Core)", "B20IJ24X150", "$9.60"],
  ["20lb White Paper 24 x 150 (2 inch Core)", "20BIJ24150", "$9.10"],
  ["24lb Premium Coated Bond Paper 24 x 150 (2 inch Core)", "24IJC24150", "$19.20"],
  ["24lb Premium Coated Bond Paper 24 x 300 (2 inch Core)", "24IJC24300", "$34.47"],
  ["36lb Coated Color Bond Paper 24 x 100 (2 inch Core)", "36IJC24100", "$23.40"],
  ["46lb Premium Coated Color Bond Paper 24 x 100 (2 inch Core)", "46IJC24100", "$33.46"],
  ["Adhesive Matte Polypropylene 24 x 100 (2 inch core)", "QM-WRPPAD-24", "$60.48"]
  ]
  var t520Printer = [
  ["36lb Coated Color Bond Paper 24 x 100 (2 inch Core)", "36IJC24100", "$23.40"],
  ["46lb Premium Coated Color Bond Paper 24 x 100 (2 inch Core)", "46IJC24100", "$33.46"],
  ["Adhesive Matte Polypropylene 24 x 100 (2 inch core)", "QM-WRPPAD-24", "$60.48"]
  ]

  
  
 
 $("#printers").change(function () {
  
  
  var e = document.getElementById("printers");
   var resulting = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  if (resulting == "HP DesignJet T120") {
   $('#testtest tbody tr').remove();
   var html = "";
   $.each(t120Printer, function(rowNum, row) {
        
    //console.log(rowNum, row);
   html += "<tr><td>" + row[0] + "<td>" + row[1] + "<td>" + row[2] + "</tr>";
        
   })

   $((html)).appendTo("#testtest tbody");
  }
  else if (resulting == "HP DesignJet T520"){
   $('#testtest tbody tr').remove();
   var html = "";
   $.each(t520Printer, function(rowNum, row){
    //console.log(rowNum, row);
    html += "<tr><td>" + row[0] + "<td>" + row[1] + "<td>" + row[2] + "</tr>"
   })

   $((html)).appendTo("#testtest tbody");
  }
  else{
      $('#testtest tbody tr').remove();
   //$((html)).appendTo("#div");
  }
  
 });


</script>
```

Comment: I tried this and it clears everything for printers that do not have any media and ink tied to them. If you switch between the first two options under hp it just adds to the table. Adding this to the else does clear it though

Comment: Yes, your code only has data for first two hp printers.

Comment: If you change from HP T120 to the HP T520 the data keeps stacking. It doesn't clear out the table unless you change it to one of the other options.

Comment: Yes, checked that. Though `$('#testtest tbody tr').remove();` is deleting the rows, your code which is adding the rows again is wrong.

Comment: Updated my answer, which will fix the data stacking as well.

Comment: That's it! Thank you for your help!! This problem has been stumping me for a while now, but I didn't want to give up. Couldn't have done it without your help